# Optional arguments in Class Functions

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am Trying to make a 2048 game in pygame using python. I want the function stackright and stackleft to operate on the self.data if no parameters are given, and return a stackrighted or stacklefted matrix if a matrix is given in the parameters.how would i go about doing this. I am using python 2.7 
here is my code:

```
import random
def getnull(): # returns null matrix
    data = [
    [0,0,2,2],
    [0,4,0,2],
    [0,2,0,0],
    [2,0,2,0]
    ]
    return data

class Data:
    def fillrandom(self): #updates data by adding 2/4 randomly
        exit = False
        while not exit:
            y = random.randint(0,3)
            x = random.randint(0,3)
            if self.data[y][x] == 0:
                if random.randint(1,10) == 1:
                    self.data[y][x] = 4
                    exit = True
                else:
                    self.data[y][x] = 2
                    exit = True
    def alignright(self):   #
        list1 = [[],[],[],[]]
        for i in range(4):          # per row loop
            for count in range(4):   # per column loop
                if self.data[i][count] != 0:
                    list1[i] += [self.data[i][count]]
            list1[i] = [0]*(4-len(list1[i])) + list1[i]
        self.data = list1
    def alignleft(self):
        list1 = [[],[],[],[]]
        for i in range(4):          # per row loop
            for count in range(4):   # per column loop
                if self.data[i][count] != 0:
                    list1[i] += [self.data[i][count]]
            list1[i] = list1[i] + [0]*(4-len(list1[i]))
        self.data = list1
    def printstate(self):
        print(self.data[0])
        print(self.data[1])
        print(self.data[2])
        print(self.data[3])
        print("-------")
    def checkfilled(self):
        for count in range(4):
            for i in range(4):
                if self.data[count][i] == 0:
                    return False
        return True
    def stackright(self):
        for i in range(4):
            if self.data[i][3] == self.data[i][2]:
                if self.data[i][1] == self.data[i][0]:
                    self.data[i][3] = self.data[i][3] *2
                    self.score += self.data[i][3]
                    self.data[i][2] = self.data[i][1] *2
                    self.score += self.data[i][2]
                    self.data[i][0] , self.data[i][1] = 0,0
                else:
                    self.data[i][3] = self.data[i][3] *2
                    self.score += self.data[i][3]
                    self.data[i][2] = self.data[i][1]
                    self.data[i][1] = self.data[i][0]
                    self.data[i][0] = 0
            elif self.data[i][2] == self.data[i][1]:
                    self.data[i][2] = self.data[i][2] *2
                    self.score += self.data[i][2]
                    self.data[i][1] = self.data[i][0]
                    self.data[i][0] = 0
            elif self.data[i][1] == self.data[i][0]:
                self.data[i][1] = self.data[i][1] *2
                self.score += self.data[i][1]
                self.data[i][0] = 0
    def stackleft(self):
        for i in range(4):
            if self.data[i][0] == self.data[i][1]:
                if self.data[i][2] == self.data[i][3]:
                    self.data[i][0] = self.data[i][0] *2
                    self.score += self.data[i][0]
                    self.data[i][1] = self.data[i][2] *2
                    self.score += self.data[i][1]
                    self.data[i][3] , self.data[i][2] = 0,0
                else:
                    self.data[i][0] = self.data[i][0]*2
                    self.score += self.data[i][0]
                    self.data[i][1] = self.data[i][2]
                    self.data[i][2] = self.data[i][3]
                    self.data[i][3] = 0
            elif self.data[i][1] == self.data[i][2]:
                    self.data[i][1] = self.data[i][1] *2
                    self.score += self.data[i][1]
                    self.data[i][2] = self.data[i][3]
                    self.data[i][3] = 0
            elif self.data[i][2] == self.data[i][3]:
                self.data[i][2] = self.data[i][2] *2
                self.score += self.data[i][2]
                self.data[i][3] = 0
    def alignup(self):
        col = [[],[],[],[]]
        for i in range(4): #per col loop
            for count in range(4): #per row loop
                if self.data[count][i] != 0:
                    col[i] += [self.data[count][i]]
            col[i] = col[i] + [0]*(4-len(col[i]))
        for i in range(4):      # convert column to row
            for count in range(4):
                self.data[count][i] = col[i][count]
    def aligndown(self):
        col = [[],[],[],[]]
        for i in range(4): #per col loop
            for count in range(4): #per row loop
                if self.data[count][i] != 0:
                    col[i] += [self.data[count][i]]
            col[i] = [0]*(4-len(col[i])) + col[i]
        for i in range(4):       # convert column to row
            for count in range(4):
                self.data[count][i] = col[i][count]
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = getnull()
        self.score = 0
data = Data()
data.aligndown()
data.printstate()
print(data.score)



while True:
    pass
```

Answer (score 3):

You can have default parameters. for example:

```
def func(self, matrix=None):
    if matrix is None:
        #do stuff with self.data
    else:
        #do stuff
```

That way if no parameters are given then the default value is None

So then you know that if the value of `matrix` is None then the caller hasn't specified a value so you do something with `self.data`. but if he does specify a value(`else`) then it means that the caller specified a value and you could do something with the matrix.

Or if you want to use them as the same value you could do the following:

```
def func(self, matrix=None):
    if matrix is None: matrix = self.data
    #do stuff with the variable 'data'
```

Now `data` is whatever you want it to be

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could do the trick:

```
def stackright(self, *args):
    if len(args) == 0:
        #do things with no arguments
    else:
        #do things with arguments
        print(args[0], args[1], ...)
```

You can also replace `*args` with `**kwargs` if you want to be able to call the parameters by their name. You can even use both:

```
def f(self, madatoryArgument1, mandatoryArgument2, *args, **kwargs)
```

The advantage of this over passing arguments with a `None` default value, is that it simplifies it when the number of arguments grows.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like for what you are asking, your functions would look like this:

```
def stackright(self, data=None):
    if data is None: data = self.data
    for i in range(4):
        if data[i][3] == data[i][2]:
            if data[i][1] == data[i][0]:
                data[i][3] = data[i][3] *2
                self.score += data[i][3]
                data[i][2] = data[i][1] *2
                self.score += data[i][2]
                data[i][0] , data[i][1] = 0,0
            else:
                data[i][3] = data[i][3] *2
                self.score += data[i][3]
                data[i][2] = data[i][1]
                data[i][1] = data[i][0]
                data[i][0] = 0
        elif data[i][2] == data[i][1]:
                data[i][2] = data[i][2] *2
                self.score += data[i][2]
                data[i][1] = data[i][0]
                data[i][0] = 0
        elif data[i][1] == data[i][0]:
            data[i][1] = data[i][1] *2
            self.score += data[i][1]
            data[i][0] = 0
    return data
def stackleft(self, data=None):
    if data == None: data = self.data
    for i in range(4):
        if data[i][0] == data[i][1]:
            if data[i][2] == data[i][3]:
                data[i][0] = data[i][0] *2
                self.score += data[i][0]
                data[i][1] = data[i][2] *2
                self.score += data[i][1]
                data[i][3] , data[i][2] = 0,0
            else:
                data[i][0] = data[i][0]*2
                self.score += data[i][0]
                data[i][1] = data[i][2]
                data[i][2] = data[i][3]
                data[i][3] = 0
        elif data[i][1] == data[i][2]:
                data[i][1] = data[i][1] *2
                self.score += data[i][1]
                data[i][2] = data[i][3]
                data[i][3] = 0
        elif data[i][2] == data[i][3]:
            data[i][2] = data[i][2] *2
            self.score += data[i][2]
            data[i][3] = 0
    return data
```

And then calling data.stackright() will operate on the self data, but calling data.stackright(matrix2) will operate on matrix2 (while adding the score to data, unless you change that part above)